# CiviBooking 1.5alpha error

Tags: civibooking

Not sure if this is best place or Github, anyway, using the 1.5alpha on CiviCRM 4.7.8 & Wordpress 4.5.3

When trying to access the Bookings - Find Bookings tab I get the following error

Fatal error: Access level to CRM_Booking_Form_Search::$_defaults must be public (as in class CRM_Core_Form) in /var/sites/h/hbb.org.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/extensions/civibooking-1.5alpha/CRM/Booking/Form/Search.php on line 10

The rest of the alpha build seems to work great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

From the error message it seems that some CiviCRM core changes made from 4.6 to 4.7 needs to be reflected in the extension code.

We will start looking into this. Please post the ticket in our extension Github: https://github.com/compucorp/civibooking and we will post responses regarding any update.

Best

Comment: The fix is now included in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

Changed line 93 in search.php to:
  public $_defaults;

now works, posted in github also.
cheers

Comment: Thanks John, we will verify the backwards compatibility of the fix.